# Accelerated C++ (Section 3.2.1: vector<double> homework)

Tags: c++, vector

In section **3.2.1 - Storing a collection of data in a vector** on page 42 of the book Accelerated C++, I came across an error in my code after following what it had told me to type.

```
// revised version of the excerpt
double x;
vector<double> homework;

// invariant: homework contains all the homework grades read so far
while (cin >> x)
    homework.push_back(x);
```

I understand the concept of vectors, but I simply don't understand why my code is giving me an error messages specifically pointing at the

```
vector<double> homework;
```

declaration. Does C++11 and C++14 not support this declaration for vectors anymore?

Here is my exact code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>

using std::cin;         using std::string;
using std::cout;        using std::setprecision;
using std::endl;        using std::streamsize;

int main()
{
    // ask for and read the student's name
    cout << "\n  Please enter your first name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "  Hello, " << name << "!" << endl;

    // ask for and read the midterm and final grades
    cout << "  Please enter your midterm and final exam grades: ";
    double midterm, final;
    cin >> midterm >> final;

    // ask for the homework grades
    cout << "  Enter all your homework grades, "
            "  followed by end-of-file: ";

    //the number and sum of grades read so far
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    // a variable into which to read
    double x;
    vector<double> homework;

    /*invariant:
    we have read COUNT grades so far, and
    SUM is the sum of the first COUNT grades*/
    while (cin >> x) {
        homework.pushback(x);
    }

    // write the result
    streamsize prec = cout.precision();
    cout << "  Your final grade is " << setprecision(3)
        << 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * final + 0.4 * sum / count
        << setprecision(prec) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error messages you're seeing? The only thing that comes to mind is `vector` not resolving. What about `std::vector<double>`? Actually, I also don't see a `<vector>` include?

Comment: `pushback` is not a member function of `std::vector`. Perhaps you mean `push_back`?

Comment: Already been answered, but thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector` resides in the header `<vector>`.  In order to use it that header needs to be included in your code.  To do that you need to `#include <vector>`.  Then you will also need to have a `using std::vector;` or use `std::vector`.

Comment: Now it is saying that .pushback is having an error

Comment: Yes, I recently just did so, it took away the error on the vector<double> homework

Comment: @NeilGraham It's `push_back` (notice underscore).

Comment: Problem solved, thank you

Comment: @NeilGraham Thank you and your welcome.